# Are tool maintenance and repair questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

It seems the community has accepted these types of questions in the past.

- [How can I clean sticky and dirty hand tool's rubber?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10631/33)
- [Is it a good idea to spraypaint my axe head?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/8917/33)
- [What are good cleaners to use on pruning shears?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5198/33)
- [How can I repair rusty tools?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10374/33)

So are tool repair and maintenance questions *still* on-topic?

Comment: Is there anything specific that prompted this question?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes.  I wondered if this [question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16361/33), could be edited to make it on-topic by making it more generic.  I thought if the question generically asked about vacuum filter change Vs. cleaning, it could be saved.

Comment: I think that one is off topic more because it's an appliance question rather than a tool question.

Comment: @ChrisF If it was about a shop-vac or dust collection system, would it be on-topic?  I was thinking of editing it so it asks if it's beneficial to replace the filter, or if cleaning it is good enough.  The two core questions asked by the user may be on-topic, just the extra information makes it off-topic (in my opinion).

Comment: @ChrisF I'm just trying to save questions here.

Comment: @Tester101 I don't mind pushing users to change their questions, but we need to be careful not to cross the line of editing the questions ourselves and changing the meaning.

Comment: @BMitch You're right.  I was inspired by the [Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), and I guess I went too far with the niceness.